# Java 8 How to manipulate objects in one list and collect them in another list?

Tags: java, lambda, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I'm fairly new to Java8. I have a requirement to convert List of POJOs to group by a certain criteria and show it on UI.

- Convert list of objects that belong to Children category to Person
  category.
- Return the List.

  ```
  Children.java
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String school;
  private String personId;
  // Setters and getters.

  Person.java
  private String fullName;
  private String address;
  // Setters and Getters.

  private Person convertChildToPerson(Children child) {
           Person person = new Person();
           person.setFullName(child.getLastName() + ", " + child.getFirstName());
            ..
            return person;
   }
  ```

  ..
      MAIN CODE..
     ..

  ```
  List<Person> personList;  // Is populated by other functions.

  // Connect to DB and gets the output
  List<Children> childrenList = (Children) criteria.list();  

  for(Children children: childrenList) {
       personList.add(convertChildToPerson(children));
  }
  return personList;
  ```

  Can't the **FOR-LOOP** present above be replaced by Java 8 Streams?

Comment: See the answer from Robert Bräutigam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 List<Person> newList = childrenList.stream()
             .map(this::convertChildToPerson)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());

 personList.addAll(newList);
```

Even shorter (and nicer), as suggested by Holger:

```
childrenList.stream()
            .map(this::convertChildToPerson)
            .forEachOrdered(personList::add);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eugene. But I already have personList which has been populated by other methods. I can't override that... So, should I have to do personList1 = .....     and then personList.addAll(personList1) ?

Comment: @SrinivasLakshman right, see edit

Comment: `forEachOrdered(personList::add)` would work too. Collecting into a new list before adding them at once may look cleaner, but implies needing temporary storage.

Comment: @Holger good suggestion, thx